# Output of a system given it's transfer function and input (beginner)

Tags: transfer-function

I have an exercise that gives me the transfer function of a system

$$H(s) = \frac{3s^2+27}{s^4+8s^3 + 16s^2} $$

and an input

$$x(t) = \frac13 cos(3t) $$

An ask's what is the output

I don't whant the answer but the steps to calculate it.

Where to start? I need to find the inverse or there's a shorcut?

Comment: I assume that the definition of $x(t)$ holds only for $t>0$, and that $x(t)=0$ for $t<0$, right?

Comment: Are you sure that the numerator isn't $3s^2+27$ (instead of $s^3$)? This would simplify the problem quite a bit.

Comment: Yes you are right its $$s^2$$ and it can be written as $$ 3 (s^2 + 3^2) $$

Comment: OK, then things cancel nicely and the result can be obtained quite easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an LTI system, output $y(t)$ is given by
$$y(t) = h(t)\otimes x(t)$$
Where $x(t)$ is input and $h(t)$ is impulse response of the system. The operator $\otimes$ represents convolution.

Convolution operation is mapped into multiplication in Laplace domain. ie,
$$Y(s) = H(s)\times X(s)$$
Where, $Y(s)$, $H(s)$ and $X(s)$ are the Laplace transform of $y(t)$, $h(t)$ and $x(t)$ respectively.

You can use any one of the above equation to solve your problem.

Two ways:

1. Find $h(t)$ from $H(s)$ and use first equation. **OR**
2. Find $X(s)$ from $x(t)$, use second equation to find $Y(s)$ and then find $y(t)$ from it.

I prefer second method.