# Frequency response of FIR (MTI delay line canceller) with non constant period

Tags: filters, frequency-response, radar

**Short question**

How to plot the magnitude of frequency response of the delay line canceller with non constant period using [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)? Or more directly: how to plot magnitude of frequency response of staggered [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_repetition_frequency) (pulse repetition frequency) [MTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_target_indication) (moving target indicator) processors?

**Full question**

I try to plot magnitude of frequency response of the MTI delay line canceller (some kind of FIR) which has the following structure using [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/):

[image: structure of the delay line canceller]

With tips in [my related post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21864/plot-the-frequency-response-of-mti-delay-line-canceller-using-octave) I can plot frequency response for constant period:

```
close all;
clear all;

T   = 1e-3;
f   = linspace (0, 2 / T, 1000);
w   = 2 .* pi .* f;
z   = exp (-j .* w .* T);
H_z = 1 - z .^ -1;

plot (f, abs (H_z), 'r', "linewidth", 2);
hold on;
grid on;
title ("Magnitude of the frequency response of the delay line canceler.");
xlabel ("Frequency.");
ylabel ("Magnitude.");
```

[image]

But now I am interesting in frequency response for non constant period:

- determinate values of period;
- random values of period.

I try to do in the following way:

```
close all;
clear all;

T_1   = 0.001;
T_2   = 0.0012;
f     = linspace (0, 2 / min (T_1, T_2), 1000);
w     = 2 .* pi .* f;
z_1   = exp (-j .* w .* T_1);
z_2   = exp (-j .* w .* T_2);
H_z_1 = 1 - z_1 .^ -1;
H_z_2 = 1 - z_2 .^ -1;
k     = 1 / 2;
H_z   = k .* (H_z_1 + H_z_2);

plot (f, abs (H_z), 'r', "linewidth", 2);
hold on;
grid on;
title ("Magnitude of the frequency response of the delay line canceler for alternate values of period T1 and T2.");
xlabel ("Frequency.");
ylabel ("Magnitude.");
```

[image]

Another words, I mean that: **common frequency response is the normalized sum of the frequency response for each value of the period**.

Am I right? If yes, is this approach will be correct for random values of period?

**Notes**

Here is some related papers, when mentioned frequency response of staggered PRF MTI processors:

- [first](https://smartech.gatech.edu/bitstream/handle/1853/15633/ewell_george_w_197405_phd_257465.pdf?sequence=3) (Pg 66 in books numeration or 81 in pdf-document numeration);
- [second](http://esl.eng.ohio-state.edu/~cbaker/cb_files/classes/ece5013/PDFs/14.%20Doppler%20Radar%20and%20MTI_2014.pdf) (Pg 32).

Comment: So, do you have any clear frequency response expression, with time varying parameters, in order to be reproduced? Similar to the sine absolute value for the previous filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want a *time-varying* delay then the whole system becomes time-varying, which means that there is no such thing as a frequency response in the conventional sense. Only linear *time-invariant* systems can be described by a frequency response. There are of course ways to describe time-varying systems, but the question is what it exactly is that you expect from such a description of the system. What you've done in your example is subtract two delayed signals from the original signal, which is in fact a time-invariant system. In sum, what you're looking for (a frequency response description of a system with a time-varying delay) does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and patient)! I have updated my question (change `Short question` and add `Notes` at the end). So now I know that what I am interesting in is called: *Frequency response of staggered PRF (pulse repetition frequency) MTI (moving target indicator) processors*. May be my question is improperly and I hope that this additional information clarify it.