# Max input of a system given it's transfer function and an assumed step change (beginner)

Tags: linear-systems, transfer-function, control-systems, laplace-transform, step-response

I have an exercise that gives me the following transfer function

$$
\frac{0.5}{s+0.5}
$$

and an assumed step change in the target of **20**

I am asked to calculate the maximum input for the assumed step change.

I know the answer is 500 but can't figure out how to get there. I have seen [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16671/output-of-a-system-given-its-transfer-function-and-input-beginner) which gives me the following but I don't know where to go from there.

$$40\,{\delta }\left(t\right)+20$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the Final Value Theorem for the Laplace Transform combined with knowing what the Laplace Transform of a unit step is. With The Final Value Theorem and given a description of the output in Laplace (which is the product of the Laplace of a unit step and the OP’s transfer function), we can easily determine the final value of the related time domain function at $t=\infty$.

I recommend studying the Final Value Theorem and related examples and you will find it to be a very easy way to determine the final value! With that you can back out what the step value needs to be to reach a final value of 500.